# Space between navbar and image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some  ugly space between my navbar and in this case an image. I have done some research on the web how to remove it, but without luck, so i would be happy if u guys could give me a solution.
This a responsive site, so when i shrink the window, the image have to be pushed down like the navbar does.

> Bootstrap
>
> ```
> <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
>     <div class="container-fluid">
>         <div class="navbar-header">
>             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
>                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>             </button>
>             <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">McNiels <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a>
>         </div>
>         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
>             <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
>                 <li><a href="home.html">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
>                 <li class="active"><a href="news.html">News<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> </a></li>
>                 <li><a href="music.html">Music <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></a></li>
>             </ul>
>             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
>                 <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
>                 <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
>             </ul>
>         </div>
>    </div>
> </nav>
>
> <img class="img-responsive" src="eminem.jpg" alt=""/>
> ```

Comment: Shouldn't that image be in container div or row? That's normally the way bootstrap works.

Answer (score 2):

Use .navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }. See working Example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">McNiels <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="news.html">News<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="music.html">Music <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/2350x550/f00" alt="" />
```

Comment: It worked, but then i ran into a new problem. I want to do the same thing, but this time it isn't an image but a carousel

Comment: The default carousel doesn't behave any differently then the individual image in my answer: removing the margin places it directly under the navbar. Unless you have an example you can share there's no other answer I can give for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

It did the work done, but does not work with carousels.
Thx